# Xamarin Azure Facebook get user info

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I've been searching on the best way to get information my azure auth from facebook.

My app is getting the authentication and the id of the user! I am not sure what code I need next in order to get the information.

So far I have this

```
if (authenticated)
{     
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var fbUser = await client.GetAsync(Appurl+".auth/me");
    var response = await fbUser.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var jo = JObject.Parse(response);
    var userName = jo["'typ':'user_id'"].ToString();
}
```

So far all the answers have left me clueless

I just need this to return name email and other Items I want.
I am sure this is an Json Parsing the wrong issue but I am not sure.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just need this to return name email and other Items I want. I am sure this is an Json Parsing the wrong issue but I am not sure.

If you visit `https://yourmobileapp .azurewebsites.net/.auth/me` from browser, and login with your FaceBook account. Then you could get the Json structs as following. It is  a **JArray** . So please have a try to use following code, it works correctly on my side.

```
  var ja = JArray.Parse(response);
  var id = ja[0]["user_id"];
```

[image]

Before that we need to add email scope on the Azure portal, about how to add email scope, please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  This was really helpful